# Formatting phone number in the particular format I want

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am working on my androd app.
I am on login with phone number screen.
My client wants phone number format like this
If length is
5 - x xxxx
6 - xx xxxx
7- xx xxxx x
8 - xx xxxx xx
9- xx xxxx xxx
10- xx xxxx xxxx
11 - xxx xxxx xxxx
12 - xxxx xxxx xxxx

I am using many ways, but sometimes app is frozen. and code is going very big.
Is there any good way to do this in simple way.in Java or Kotlin

Comment: Please add the code that you tried.

Comment: The obvious way is to use a `switch` statement.  I don't see why that isn't "good enough".  However, it would probably be more productive for you to show us your code ... and we can maybe explain why it is freezing.

Comment: **I am using many ways, but sometimes app is frozen. and code is going very big** indicates that your problem is somehow **much more basic**: you seem to not know what you are doing. Meaning: the fact that your app freezes means that something is going **really really wrong**. Which means: you have to learn how to **debug** such problems. The solution here isn't that you pick up some code that the internet throws at you. The solution is ... that you have to spend the time it takes to **learn how to debug** your code. And how to properly structure it ...

Comment: Seriously: you can't have it both ways. You can't promise a client to do work for them, but then assume that *other* people out there on the internet do the heavy lifting for you for free.

Comment: Finally: you also want to learn how this community works. Please spend some time at [help] to really learn how / what to ask here. And then yes, read [mcve] and show us the **essentials** of your "not working" code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have Android default Library for this

com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.Phonemetadata
com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil

```
    // Mobile Number Formatter()
fun mobileNumberFormatterList(): MutableList<Phonemetadata.NumberFormat>{
    val newNumberFormats: MutableList<Phonemetadata.NumberFormat> =
        ArrayList()

    newNumberFormats.add(digitFormatterLength5())
    newNumberFormats.add(digitFormatterLength6())
    newNumberFormats.add(digitFormatterLength7())
    ... ... ...
}

    private fun digitFormatterLength5() : Phonemetadata.NumberFormat{
    val numberFormat: Phonemetadata.NumberFormat = Phonemetadata.NumberFormat()
    numberFormat.pattern = "(\\d{1})(\\d{4})"
    numberFormat.format = "$1 $2"

    return numberFormat
}
    private fun digitFormatterLength6() : Phonemetadata.NumberFormat{
    val numberFormat: Phonemetadata.NumberFormat = Phonemetadata.NumberFormat()
    numberFormat.pattern = "(\\d{2})(\\d{4})"
    numberFormat.format = "$1 $2"

    return numberFormat
}

editTextMobile.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            // Reformat mobile number with spacings
            if (isChangedTextByUser) {
                reformatMobileNumber(editTextMobile)
            }

        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }
    })

    private fun reformatMobileNumber(editTextMobile: EditText) {

    val phoneNumberUtil: PhoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance()

    var phoneNumberPN: Phonenumber.PhoneNumber? = null

    try {
        phoneNumberPN = phoneNumberUtil.parse(countryCode +
                editTextMobile.text.toString(), countryCodePicker?.selectedCountryNameCode!!)
        val phoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.formatByPattern(
            phoneNumberPN,
            PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL,
            FormatterUtils.mobileNumberFormatterList()
        )
        editTextMobile.setText(phoneNumber)
              phoneNumber.replace("""[$, ]""".toRegex(), "").also { strMobile = it }

        editTextMobile.setSelection(editTextMobile.text!!.length)
    } catch (e: NumberParseException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Comment: How to use that pattern arraylist?

Comment: You see, that is the problem when you throw some code at newbies without any further explanations: they don't understand what you are trying to tell them. Me, I am wondering, too how that list of formatters should be used later on. Wouldnt you rather use a map for example, where the key is the number of digits in the number, and the value is the corresponding formatter?

Comment: I will update  answer @HJaison

Comment: haha, I agree @GhostCat

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this on your activity or fragment.

```
etMobile.addTextChangedListener(new TextFormatter(etMobile, "### ### ####"));
```

Comment: And how does that work for the requirement of using different formatting, depending on the length?

Comment: He can simple use condition statement.

Comment: When you read the question carefully, you might note that the OP already has "a lot of code". The real problem here is that we have **no** idea how exactly the OP has structured their code, and what they are **actually** struggling with. Such questions should be close voted. And if you really think you want to answer them, then your answer should make up for the lack of quality in the question. Just throwing some code at the OP, and going "yeah, needs something around it, too" isn't that.